# SharePoint list alert issues

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I've got alert set up on one of the lists. When I subscribe the user to the list changes - the user gets "has subscribed you for alert " email. However, when list items are added/change - no alert is sent out.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This troubleshooting guide may help

http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

[image: Troubleshooting flowchart]

Comment: I think this is right and I'm having the timer job issue. What would be the timer job called? I can't find anything "e-mailish"? May be this is the problem?

Comment: Follow the link to "Check SharePoint Timer Jobs" and it will tell all ;)   http://sharepointalert.info/2009/11/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts-timer-jobs/

Comment: I marked this as the answer even though I'm still looking for the actual problem, but I think the answer is somewhere there :)